# sharepoint designer 2007- Redirect to another Page after adding List Item

Tags: sharepoint

I am using SP Designer 2007 to display the custom list form. Users will use this form to fill in the details and click on submit. Once they submit, they will be stored in the list.

But it redirect to Allitems.aspx of the list rather then confirmation page.

How do I redirect to custom page.

When clicking on the cancel button I need to redirect to the default.aspx page.

This is what my code looks in SP designer 2007.

Where do I specify the redirect attribute in the below code?

```
<table>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap=""><IMG SRC="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"/></td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="">
                            <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" Text="Submit" id="savebutton2" source=""/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="ms-separator"> </td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="" align="right">
                            <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="gobackbutton2"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the onclick event of your submit button add something like this:

```
javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={submitted.aspx};')}
```